# Out of a group of 60 people, 20 invested in the stock market, 35 had certificates of deposit (CD’s), and 34 had savings bonds.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Out of a group of 60  people, 20 invested in the stock market,  35 had certificates of deposit (CD’s), and  34 had savings bonds. Furthermore,23   had both CD’s and bonds,  13 had both stocks and CD’s, and 13 had both bonds and stocks. Finally,10  of the people had no investments.
i.  Determine how many people had all three types of investments.
ii. Use the value obtained in (i) to represent information in a Venn diagram. 
iii.    How many people did not invest in stock market at all?
iv. How many people invested in atleast one investment?

(so far i have tried to generate the formulars, i have done one like this before but this one is challenging, especially the first one and second one.)

Answer (score 0):

```
This amounts to solving a system having the following augmanted matrix by row operations:


1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   35
0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   20
0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   34
0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   23
0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   13
0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   13
```

Answer (score 0):

For i) you have to apply the inclusion–exclusion principle.

$|B \cup C \cup S|=|B|+|C|+|S|-|B \cap C|-|B\cap S|-|C \cap S|+|B \cap C \cap S|$

$B$=Set of people, which had saving bonds.

$C$=Set of people, which had certificates of deposit.

$S$=Set of people, which invested in the stock market.

$\Rightarrow |B \cap C \cap S|=|B \cup C \cup S|-|B|-|C|-|S|+|B \cap C|+|B\cap S|+|C \cap S|$

$|B \cap C \cap S|=50-34-35-20+23+13+13=50-89+49=10$

Remark: Because of 10 people had no investments $|B \cup C \cup S|=60-10=50$

What kind of problems do you have with ii) ?